# asp.net mvc core updating partial with ajax doesn't run javascript function on html elements in partial

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have an asp.net mvc core 2.2 application.  On a page I am loading a partial:

```
<div class="col-md-9" id="content">
    @await Html.PartialAsync("_TrainingContent")
</div>
```

the partial has a model and loads a video using video.js player:

```html
@model Partner2Train.Models.ModuleViewModels.TrainingContentViewModel

@if (Model != null)
{
    <li>Do some training stuff for @Model.ModuleId</li>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="instructions">
            <video id="my_video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="640" height="267"
                   poster=''
                   data-setup='{ "aspectRatio":"640:267", "playbackRates": [0.5, 1, 2], "controls":true, "preload":"auto", "autoplay":false, "inactivityTimeout":0 }'>

                <source src="~/video/sample_video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                <source src="~/video/sample_video.webm" type="video/webm" />
                <source src="~/video/sample_video.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
                <p>Your browser does not support HTML5 video.</p>
            </video>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row" style="margin-top:25px;">
        <div id="db_data">
            <label>Current video location: </label> <input type="text" id="watched_value" value="" disabled /><br />
            <label>Total video duration: </label> <input type="text" id="total_duration" value="" disabled />
        </div>
    </div>
    <br /><br />

}
else
{
    <text>Please select a module</text>
}
```

If I have the javascript functions that modify the div and load the video run on document ready the video loads and you can play it.  However, when I update the partial with an ajax call:

```js
$("#tcontent").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "Module/TrainingContent/?id=2",
        type: "get",
        //data: $("form").serialize(), //if you need to post Model data, use this
        success: function (result) {
            $("#content").html(result);
        }
    });
})
```

The video no longer loads.  The ajax call will eventually return an updated model to display in the partial, different video, text etc.  I assume this didn't work because the ajax doesn't trigger a load of a page so the video javascript doesn't load again.  So I moved the video javascript into a function and call it on success of the ajax call:

```js
$("#tcontent").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "Module/TrainingContent/?id=2",
        type: "get",
        //data: $("form").serialize(), //if you need to post Model data, use this
        success: function (result) {
            $("#content").html(result);
            vidprep();
            vidbutton();
        }
    });
})
```

However, I get the same result in that it doesn't load the controls.  The functions run, as I can see some debug text in the console, but will not add the video controls just showing a box with an unformatted first frame.

If you are updating a partial with ajax how do you get JavaScript to act on the elements in the partial?

Any help would be much appreciated as I have been stuck on this for a couple days.

Elements after ajax call[image: elements after ajax call]

Here are my two JS functions that do run, messages print to console:

```js
function vidprep() {

    console.log("In partial video function");
    // Stop if HTML5 video isn't supported
    if (!document.createElement('video').canPlayType) {
        $("#video_controls").hide();
        console.log("Can't Play Video");
        return;
    }

    var video = document.getElementById("my_video");

    // Play/Pause ============================//
    $("#play_button").bind("click", function () {
        video.play();
    });

    $("#pause_button").bind("click", function () {
        video.pause();
    });

    $("#play_toggle").bind("click", function () {
        if (video.paused) {
            video.play();
            $(this).html("Pause");
        } else {
            video.pause();
            $(this).html("Play");
        }
    });

    // Play Progress ============================//
    $(video).bind("timeupdate", function () {
        var timePercent = (this.currentTime / this.duration) * 100;
        $("#play_progress").css({ width: timePercent + "%" })
    });

    // Load Progress ============================//
    $(video).bind("progress", function () {
        updateLoadProgress();
    });
    $(video).bind("loadeddata", function () {
        updateLoadProgress();
    });
    $(video).bind("canplaythrough", function () {
        updateLoadProgress();
    });
    $(video).bind("playing", function () {
        updateLoadProgress();
    });

    function updateLoadProgress() {
        if (video.buffered.length > 0) {
            var percent = (video.buffered.end(0) / video.duration) * 100;
            $("#load_progress").css({ width: percent + "%" })
        }
    }

    // Time Display =============================//
    $(video).bind("timeupdate", function () {
        $("#current_time").html(formatTime(this.currentTime));
        $("#watched_value").val(formatTime(this.currentTime));
    });
    $(video).bind("durationchange", function () {
        $("#duration").html(formatTime(this.duration));
        $("#total_duration").val(formatTime(this.duration));
    });

    function formatTime(seconds) {
        var seconds = Math.round(seconds);
        var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
        // Remaining seconds
        seconds = Math.floor(seconds % 60);
        // Add leading Zeros
        minutes = (minutes >= 10) ? minutes : "0" + minutes;
        seconds = (seconds >= 10) ? seconds : "0" + seconds;
        return minutes + ":" + seconds;
    }
}

function vidbutton() {
    var $refreshButton = $('#refresh');
    var $results = $('#css_result');
    console.log("In video button");
    function refresh() {
        var css = $('style.cp-pen-styles').text();
        $results.html(css);
    }

    refresh();
    $refreshButton.click(refresh);

    // Select all the contents when clicked
    $results.click(function () {
        $(this).select();
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you inspected the result? Is it valid HTML?

Comment: Try adding `dataType: "html"` to the options of your `$.ajax` call.

Comment: @BlueWater86.  If you mean in the partial after the ajax call the the same as what I have for the partial, the javascript functions don't add anything.  They should modify the html I have adding int the controls, like it does on page load.

Comment: The `result` variable; have you inspected this? You say you are not getting anything rendered, therefore your result variable must not contain valid HTML.

Comment: @BlueWater86 Thanks for the quick suggestion.  Still no go, same result as before, html in partial is unmodified even though the functions run.

Comment: Please include the result of the ajax call in your question.

Comment: @BlueWater86 to clarify I do see a still image of the first frame of the video and the result does have a valid mvc model becuase it is outputting updated text in the partial.  It is just the scripts are not modifying the elements in the partial when updated with an ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Have you include js file and debug in browser?